# Using select filter in ngTable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I was trying this ngTable [example](http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-select) of filtering columns using select values. 
HTML code (table part)

```
 <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
      <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{name: 'select'}" filter-data="names" sortable="'name'">{{ row.name }}</td>
      <td data-title="'Age'" filter="{age: 'text'}" sortable="'age'">{{ row.age }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript code

```
var app = angular.module('ngTableApp', ['ngTable'])
      .controller('selectFilterController', function($scope, $filter, $q, NgTableParams) {
        var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                    {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                    {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                    {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                    {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                    {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                    {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                    {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                    {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                    {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                    {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                    {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                    {name: "Enos", age: 34}
                ];
        $scope.names = ['Moroni', 'Enos', 'Nephi'];
        $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({page: 1, count: 10}, {dataset: data});

      })
```

When I run this code [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qj6i6MwpSDx66X5rtobm?p=info), the select values for column 'Name' are blank.

The [example](http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-select) says

> The select filter will fetch its data by calling the **fetchData** function defined for the column.

But, there is no **fetchData** function called in the code in that example. I am confused as what is the issue here?

Comment: Check the errors in plunker..

Comment: @RayonDabre Looks like an issue with plunker. The same code in my local machine shows no errors (but the same issue mentioned in my Question).

Answer (score 0):

From [example](http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-select) I figured out that the format used by ng-table for ***filter-data*** attribute in HTML(for select values) is array of objects in the following form.

```
$scope.names = [{id: "", title: ""}, {id: 'Moroni', title: 'Moroni'}, {id: 'Enos', title: 'Enos'}, {id: 'Nephi', title: 'Nephi'}];
```

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qj6i6MwpSDx66X5rtobm).

Answer (score 0):

Should be written like:

```
$scope.names = [{"id": "", "title": ""}, {"id": "Moroni", "title": "Moroni"}];
```